# eclipse How can I define how many spaces the IDE uses when it autocomplete?

Tags: eclipse, spacing

I lose a lot of time putting right amount of spaces in my code, going back and forward with cursor, for it to look exactly the way I like it... example:

```
    identifier space assignmentOperator
    space someFunction space leftParenthesis 
    space argument space rightParenthesis space semicolon
```

code example:

```
 char character = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Introduce the
 character that is gonna draw the rectangle" ).charAt ( 0 ) ;
```

This way everything looks a lot better to me, but when eclipse autocompletes it doesn't use any of those spaces, so I have to put them by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually quite a lot to see here:

http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse